# Azure pipeline is running old version files (before last commit)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to run a pipeline with Azure DevOps, I have a problem that it's not running the tests of the current version in the master branch. It's running older files, files from the old commit. I don't know why this is happening. The old files shouldn't be run because they don't exist anymore in the master branch after the last pull request is complete and merged.
Has anyone any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Mohamed,
Can I confirm some info with you?
1. What pipeline did you run the test ? Build pipeline or release pipeline?
2. Please share some screenshot of the pipeline summary page(Repository and version) and repo commit page in the issue description. Check if the commit ID is the latest commit and then kindly share the result with us.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT It's a build pipeline. I can't share some screenshots because of the security involved to the organization. Sorry.

Comment: I tried to clear the cache of the pipeline and I'm running it again now.

Comment: Ok, please try it and then kindly share the result with us.
In addition, open the latest build->summary->we can see the tab Repository and version, please check the branch and commit info.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT It worked perfectly after clearing the cache of the pipeline. But I just still having an issue. Some tests fail in the pipeline, but they work fine locally. Do you have any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT , I just accepted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mohamed for sharing and confirming.

Summary.

Issue description:

Azure pipeline is running old commit version files instead of latest commit.

Answer:

According to Mohamed's description： It worked perfectly after clearing the cache of the pipeline.

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly do you clear cache of the pipeline, please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-clear-a-cache